# Selecting element decendants by attribute

Tags: dart, dart-html

in the following html i want to select the descendants of the view tag by attribute name

```dart
<view data-context="testviewmodel">
       <div>
         id:<input data-bind-two-way="model.id">
         name:<input data-bind-two-way="model.name">
         description:<input data-bind-two-way="model.description">
       </div>

       <div>
         id:<input data-bind-two-way="model.id">
         name:<input data-bind-two-way="model.name"> 
         description<input data-bind-two-way="model.description"> 
       </div>

       <div>
         <p>{{model.id}}</p>
         <p>{{model.name}}</p>
         <p>{{model.description}}</p>
       </div>           
    </view>
```

so i should get 6 elements (the 6 input elements that have the attribute `data-bind-two-way`) however i wrote the following recursive function and it gives me a list of 3 elements which are the first three descendant input elements

```dart
 static List<Element> decendantSelector(Element rootElement,{List<Element> collectedElements:null,
                                                       List<String> targetAttributes:null,
                                                       bool mustHaveAllAttributes:false}){

    if(collectedElements==null)
      collectedElements = new List<Element>();


    for(Element child in rootElement.children){
      bool haveAllAttributesFlag = true;
      for(String attrName in targetAttributes){
        if(child.attributes.containsKey(attrName)){
          collectedElements.add(child);
        } else {
          haveAllAttributesFlag = false;
        }
        if(!haveAllAttributesFlag && mustHaveAllAttributes)
          break;
      }
      if(child.hasChildNodes())
          return  decendantSelector(child,
              collectedElements:collectedElements,
              targetAttributes:targetAttributes,
              mustHaveAllAttributes:false);
    }
    return collectedElements;
  }
```

used it as

```dart
List<Element> descendantsWithAttributeDataBindTwoWay = decendantSelector(querySelector('view'),targetAttributes:['data-bind-two-way']);
```

any idea why the descendants in the second div get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of this return statement

```dart
if(child.hasChildNodes())
          return  decendantSelector(child,
```

remove just the `return` and it will work.

Have you considered something like

```dart
Set<Element> result = new Set<Element>();
result.addAll(querySelectorAll('view [data-bind-two-way]'));
// repeat the same with other combinations until you have covered all cases
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion pretty useful didn't know such thing existed

Comment: The document and each DOM node have the methods `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()`. This is quite powerful. I'm not sure but I think all selectors described here can be used
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html